# form with spans inline and block in relation to input text

Tags: html, css

Im learning about css and Im trying to draw a form with 3 columns but Im having some difficulties.

First Im using 3 fieldsets and Im floating each one at left, this is correct to do? Or for example should we float the first two columns at left and the last at right?

Then Im trying to do something with the layout but Im with some difficulties to achieve it correctly. The first and second column it is ok I want this layout:

```
Product                  User

InputTextBelowSpan       InputTextBelowSpan
```

But it the third column I want something different, with the span and the inputs inline, like this:

```
Product               User                 hashcod  InputTextInlineWithSpan

InputTextBelowSpan   InputTextBelowSpan    hashcod  InputTextInlineWithSpan
```

But Im with some difficulties doing this, having the inputs below span in the first and second columns and the inputs inline with the span in the third column. The difficulty is to have all inputs with the same width using percentanges, so the layout ajudsts to the browser width.

Do you know how to do this?

This is what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/e8fh5beb/

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form">

    <fieldset class="form_left">
      <label>
        <span>Product</span>
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>Cod</span>
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form_left ">
      <label>
        <span>User</span>
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
      <label>
        <span>ID</span>
        <input type="text"/>
      </label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form_left last">
      <label>
        <span class="hashcod">hashcod</span>
        <input class="hashcod" type="text"/>
      </label> 
      <label>
        <span class="hashcod">hashcod</span>
        <input class="hashcod" type="text"/>
      </label> 
    </fieldset>

  </form>
</div>
```

Css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

.form{
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}

.form_left{
    float:left;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    width: 32%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.form_left.last{margin-right:0;}


fieldset{border:0;}
label{width:100%; margin-bottom: 20px; display: block;}
label span{display:block; margin-bottom: 8px; color:#717f86;}
input{padding: 10px; width: 100%;}

.hashcod{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You just need to make your selectors **more specific** to the areas they are in. Rather than setting **all** spans to `display:block` just do that to the ones in the left/center.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And in your opinion having the three fieldsets floated at left its correct?

Comment: If that's what you want...no reason not to. Depends on your design.